# Array of variables in VBA

Tags: vba

I have an code length issue I would like to hear your expertise about.

I have a class, called MyClass, with several Properties, P1, P2,...P16.

The values I want to put in the properties are in an array, called MyArray.

Right now, what I am doing, and it is working fine is:

```
MyClass.P1 = MyArray(0)
...
MyClass.P16 = MyArray(15)
```

It takes a lot of lines, and the code is not very readable.

I would like to be able to loop through the variables, like

```
For i = 0 to 15
    array_of_variables(0) = MyArray(0)
Next
```

However, I have no idea on how to create this 'array_of_variables'.

I have tried creating a property of the class as an Array, but that is not correct VBA :(.

Do you have any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot,
Maxime

Comment: There is usually a field that'll take a variable string. Let's say you have forms, but you want to use a string to reuse your code. You could use `string = "FormName"` and then `Forms(string).blabla`. Try looking for `MyClass.Properties()` or `MyClass.Fields()` or something similar in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection if you wanted a dirty way to do it, setup your class with a single collection of properties with predefined keys(names) and also use this same format with the collection your going to pass to the class and look through each name finding the match between the 2 collections and transferring the values. i guess you could do the same thing with an array but you would have to make sure the data in them is aligned, unlike collections that have names to identify them arrays only have indexes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

place the following in your "MyClass" Class Module

```
Public Properties As Variant
```

and here follows a possible exploitation of that

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim MyClassInstance As MyClass
Dim i As Long

Set MyClassInstance = New MyClass

With MyClassInstance
    .Properties = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

    For i = LBound(.Properties) To UBound(.Properties)
        MsgBox .Properties(i)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your suggestions, I came up with something mixing them all.

In the class I created the property like this:

```
Property Let Target(index, Value)
    Select Case index
        Case 0:
        P1 = Value
        ...
        Case 15
        P16 = Value
    End Select
End Property
```

This way, I can loop like this:

```
For i = 0 to 15
    MyClass.Target(i) = MyArray(i)
Next
```

Comment: glad we helped. anyhow this way you still have to hard code all properties in the Class (`P1= Value`, `P2= Value`,...) both for their names and for the `Select Case - Case` block. Moreover are you going to use `P1`, `P2` as public properties? If so, that would lead to one more "restriction" of your code. You may want to share more info about your needs to let us be more helpful. Finally if you may want to up-vote any answer useful to you. cheers